# How large is the ground state degeneracy of additive quantum codes?

Tags: quantum-information, topological-order

### General Question:

Let $\mathcal H$ denote a Hilbert space of $n$ qubits. I guess that implies that the dimensionality of $\mathcal H$ is $2^n.$ Now, suppose that I specify a Hamiltonian

$$H = H(A,B,...) \,,$$

where $A,B,...\in \mathcal L(\mathcal H).$ Moreover, I specify a set of constraints

$$ f^{(i)}(A,B,...)=0 \,,$$

where $i = 1,...,m.$

Given this setting, is it true that the ground state of my system is going to be $2^m$-fold degenerate? If yes, why? If not, what decides the dimensionality of my ground state manifold?

---

### Special Question:

In page 3 of [Fault-tolerant quantum computation by anyons](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9707021), I believe Kitaev says that the above conclusion *follows from the general theory of additive quantum codes*, and refers to two papers that are too general (and advanced) for my understanding.

Can anybody summarise the *general* theory for me so that I can see how the conclusion follows?

---

Thank you very much for your time.

---

### EDIT:

I do not believe my question is in any way the equivalent of [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29400/76347). The premise of the linked question is the conclusion of mine, which is that counting the number of independent constraints is equivalent to counting the degeneracy of the ground state.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ground state degeneracy of a variation of Toric Code model](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29400/)

Comment: @EverettYou Are you kidding me? The linked question asks about a very specific question. I'm asking a very general question. Even my special question doesn't coincide with the linked question. The Hamiltonians are different.  (P.S. I hope this is not because of my not accepting your answer, which you deleted.)

Comment: @J.Rahaman The specific question illustrates how to count the ground state degeneracy in details. For your general question, I do not think it is a correct question, i.e. given your general setting, the ground state degeneracy will **not** be $2^m$ in general. The $2^m$ result is a special result which is only valid for Z2 toric code. But the method to obtain this result is based on the "general theory of additive quantum codes", which I illustrated in details in the other question.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I realized that it was a useless answer to an incorrect question. My new answer to your question is: for the general question, the answer is no, the ground state degeneracy is not determined by this general setup; for the special question of how to count the ground state degeneracy of Z2 toric code, please refer to the linked question for details.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. There is an explicit assumption in the linked question: **if the Hamiltonian is a sum of commuting projectors, then counting the number of independent constraints is equivalent to counting the degeneracy of the ground state.** Does your answer attempt in any way to prove this claim? Or, does it accept that the "*counting method*" is impractical for the modified Hamiltonian (which is no longer the Z2 toric code, mind you!) and tries to use a different method (loop algebra) to count the ground state degeneracy? Is it too much to ask for a proof of the counting method?

Comment: @EverettYou Do you label every question that can possibly be answered with a "*no*" as ***incorrect***? I do not know if your answer was really useless, but why do you say my question is incorrect?

Comment: Moreover, the papers that Kitaev referred to for *"the general theory of additive quantum codes"* talk about group theoretic treatment of generic error correcting codes and their description using stabilizers of subspaces spanned by code words. The specific example of the Z2 toric code is never discussed in these papers. So tell me, when did you ever attempt to summarise *the general theory of additive quantum codes* for me?